# Addresses, Geolocation and driving times

Tags: distance, mapping, network-analysis, driving

I have a list of addresses (Germany and Austria) that I

1. want to display on a map (easy)
2. from a random point on the map obtain a list of all the addresses that are within a driving time of x mins (hard).

for 2) can this be done with ArcGIS (I have a student account), and are there data sets that estimate driving times between different points (Germany and Austria) that are readily available and can be used for this?

Any other ideas on how to approach this problem? Is there another tool that comes to mind to solve this problem?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.  Also, some of your questions look like they may be about open data, and for those I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: What about PgRouting?